# PHP - PDO return escaping slash, how to remove it?

Tags: php, pdo

I am doing some select with PDO object, but after `fetch` result, I got string with escaped `'` to `\'`, how can I disable that?

Comment: `magic_quotes` where disabled from PHP 5.4 onwards. So luckily this will not be an issue any more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you might be having some trouble with [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). You can disable them by following [the instructions here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). It's highly recommended that you disable them instead of sidestepping them by using a function to just strip the slashes out.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on.

You should actually **turn off** the magic quotes from **php.ini**.

Or from within script, you can handle it like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
  $str = stripslashes($str);
}
```

Now you can use the `$str` variable normally.

Comment: It's probably best to check if magic_quotes is actually enabled before stripping slashes, otherwise you'll be removing slashes that are meant to be left intact.

Comment: @tdammers: I updated the answer with this before this comment, thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a shared-hosting that I didn't have access to `php.ini` -- `ini_set()` won't work also. This snippet worked like a charm: [[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)]

```
// since PHP 5
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_gpc(&$value)
    {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
   array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes_gpc');
   array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
   array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes_gpc');
   array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, 'stripslashes_gpc');
}
```