# PHP and MYSQL cannot display double quotes properly when also displaying ñ correctly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, character-encoding, special-characters

I am having issues inserting double quotes into my mysql database.

I had to change headers to UTF8 since I will be displaying Spanish (ñ, accents).

I run a page (PHP) to insert a message in my database:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$newMessage = $_POST['newChatMessage'];
$currentUser = $_SESSION['mundialUser'];
$currentUserId = $_SESSION['idPlayer'];
$newMessage = $_POST['newChatMessage'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$messageDate = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

$chatMessageQuery = "INSERT INTO chat (message, user, user_id, date) values (:message, :user, :user_id, :date)";
$con->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$chatMessage = $con->prepare($chatMessageQuery);
$chatMessage->execute(array(':message'=>$newMessage, ':user'=>$currentUser, ':user_id'=>$currentUserId, ':date'=>$messageDate));
```

When I check in the database, double quotes come up like \" instead of simply ". The Spanish ñ is inserted like this: ÃƒÂ±.

Then to display, my main page has this in the Head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

And I print the message retrieved from the database using `utf8_decode`.

The outcome is: the Spanish ñ shows correctly but the double quotes are displayed like `\"` and not `"`

What am I missing when inserting into my db or displaying?

Comment: Can you try it without simple-quoting the "utf8" when you're doing the "SET NAMES 'utf8'"? Also can you check your file encoding is UTF-8 ?

Comment: Same thing. ñ is ok, " comes out \"

Comment: A bad solution can be add a stripslashes around your utf8_decode, but it's ugly. I can see you don't sanitize your $_SESSION and $_POST data, maybe the $_POST values are bad before added in your db... Is the magic_quote_gpc disabled from your apache?

Comment: magic_quote_gpc seems to be  ON

Comment: ow, so if you can, set it to OFF. The magic_quote_gpc will "magically" add a backslash before quotes for all of your $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE data (gpc = Get, Post, Cookie). This is now a deprecated usage. If you can't, the only way to deal with is to sanitize all of your $_GET, $_POST or $_COOKIE data from backslashes using the stripslashes PHP function. Don't forget to restart your apache if you remove the mqgpc.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382331/php-pdo-return-escaping-slash-how-to-remove-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> double quotes come up like \" instead of simply "

Some of your code is adding these slashes. Or ancient feature of magic quotes is turned off. Either should be disabled.

> The Spanish ñ is inserted like this: ÃƒÂ±.

It makes very little sense sending mysql **init** command when the actual init has been done already.

`SET NAMES` is not a magic chant that require some special dance to perform, but rather plain and simple SQL query. So, you can run it via `query()` method. Or, better, set charset in DSN.

Answer (score -1):

You should look the charset of you tables/database. At least in Portuguese it can be a headache

Comment: this little snippet saved me once: `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');`, but It's really a shot in the dark; There's a lot of points on a web app that can mess up with your codification

Comment: At which stage should I add this? Before insertion?

Comment: These mb_* method are useful when dealing with multibytes encoding but I don't see any mb_* calls in your code. So mb_internal_encoding() won't help here, and also shouldn't be placed in PHP source code but in your php.ini. Use the directive mbstring.internal-encoding

Comment: As I said, this is a shot in the dark. Can't see a reason for downvote since wrong charset is a very commom cause for this kind of problem