# backward slashes being added after fetching data from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I have a link saved in the database such as `http://www.example.com/`
and fetch the data with PDO, it comes back like `http:\/\/www.example.com\/`. I thought it might be a problem with the MySQL database, but when I tried to do it with MySQLi functions it was returned correctly. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How are you actually storing this, and how are you trying to display it? This could matter a great deal. Please show a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382331/php-pdo-return-escaping-slash-how-to-remove-it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili That doesn't address the source of this problem, it just undoes it, piling hack atop bug.

Comment: Can you add your PDO fetching code and the `mysqli` code that works for comparison?